# Can we create a calendar event webhook on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Can I get details of calendar events via webhook in our app after a user creates an event?


[image: workflow picture]


If I can do that, please help me how to set the callback URL for that.

Comment: I have exactly same issues, does anyone knows, what can we do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0 Outlook event  Changes to all events in a user's mailbox:
/users/{id}/events